# Binding ObservableCollection contained in ViewModel to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2012

I've searched and searched but can't obtain a proper, helpful answer.

I have a MainWindow wpf window. Its DataContext is set to its ViewModel.

I have a ListView which is binded to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" Name="sources_ListView" Grid.RowSpan="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sources}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="290" Header="Name"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OriginalPath}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Type" 
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

RelayCommand:

```
        public ICommand BrowseFileFolderCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_browseFileFolderCommand == null)
                {
                    _browseFileFolderCommand = new RelayCommand(o => 
                               {
                                  _sources.Add(new SourceItem(selectedPath, new DirectoryInfo(selectedPath)));
                               }, null);
                }
                return _browseFileFolderCommand;
            }
        }
```

Now obviously what the Lambda function does, wouldn't work in the real world as I have taken it out of context, but accept the fact that it does add SourceItem to the ObservableCollection _sources and that there is a Public Sources which gets the _sources. I have also made the type that ObservableCollection takes use INotifyChangedProperty.

When I use that RelayCommand which is inside a button which adds a source to the ObservableCollection, the ListView doesn't update?

Thanks for any help

EDIT SourceItem:

```
public class SourceItem : ISourceItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DirectoryInfo _sourceFolder;
    public DirectoryInfo SourceFolder { get { return _sourceFolder; } private set { _sourceFolder = value; } }

    FileInfo _sourceFile;
    public FileInfo SourceFiles { get { return _sourceFile; } private set { _sourceFile = value; } }

    string _originalPath;
    public string OriginalPath { get { return _originalPath; } private set { _originalPath = value; OnPropertyChanged("OriginalPath"); } }

    bool _isFolder;
    public bool IsFolder { get { return _isFolder; } }

    // display friendly property of IsFolder
    public string Type { get { return _isFolder == true ? "Folder" : "File"; } }

    public SourceItem(string originalPath, DirectoryInfo sourceFolder)
    {
        _originalPath = originalPath;
        _sourceFolder = sourceFolder;
        _sourceFile = null;

        _isFolder = true;
    }

    public SourceItem(string originalPath, FileInfo sourceFile)
    {
        _originalPath = originalPath;
        _sourceFile = sourceFile;
        _sourceFolder = null;

        _isFolder = false;
    }



    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    #region Debugging Aides

    /// <summary>
    /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
    /// a public property with the specified name. This 
    /// method does not exist in a Release build.
    /// </summary>
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real.
        // public, instance property on this object
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = String.Format("Invalid property name: {0}", propertyName);

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
    /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
    /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might 
    /// override this property's getter to return true.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: 1 - Post your Observablecollection definition. 2 - Did you look at the VS debug output for any binding errors?

Comment: 1. Done, 2. No errors appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the public version of the property to add the new item

```
Sources.Add(new SourceItem(selectedPath, new DirectoryInfo(selectedPath)));
```

You are currently adding the item to the private version of your property (`_sources`), while your UI is bound to the public version of the property (`Sources`), so your UI does not get the `CollectionChanged` notification the private version of the property raises, so does not know it needs to update.

The alternative is to simply raise the `PropertyChanged` event for your class manually to tell the UI to update. This is usually what I do when I want to add a lot of items to my collection at the same time, but only have the UI update once.

```
_sources.Add(new SourceItem(selectedPath, new DirectoryInfo(selectedPath)));
RaisePropertyChanged("Sources");
```

Comment: But what about instantiation?

Comment: @No1_Melman I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What about instantiation? Usually my ObservableCollections are created either in the Constructor, or in the `get` method of the property if the private version of the property is `null`

Comment: Where does RaisePropertyChanged come from?

Comment: AHHHHHHHH, that worked, I guessed that RaisePropertyChanged was my OnPropertyChanged which implements INotifyPropertyChanged in my ViewModelBase and it worked. Genius

Comment: another quick question, does that mean that my SourceItem doesn't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged then because it is all getting handled by my ViewModel?

Comment: @No1_Melman The `PropertyChanged` in your `ViewModel` is only handling the cases where your `ObservableCollection Sources` changes to a new `ObservableCollection` or `null`, and the `ObservableCollection` class itself handles change notification in cases where items get added or removed from the collection. The `PropertyChange` code on the `SourceItem` will alert the UI if the properties on the `SourceItem` get changed, so if there's a chance they change and that change needs to be reflected in the UI, you should keep the `INotifyPropertyChange` on that class